# raspbmc: Unable to exit sqlite3 after incorrect syntax even with semicolon

Tags: raspbmc, sqlite

I was using sqlite to connect to `MyVideos75.db` when I noticed that the usual method of getting "un-stuck" from the sqlite prompt (entering a semicolon) wasn't working:

```
pi@raspbmc:~/.xbmc/userdata/Database$ sqlite3 MyVideos75.db 
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from files where strFilename like %Recreation%';
   ...> 
   ...> ;
   ...> ;
   ...> .quit
   ...> ;
   ...> .exit
   ...> ;
   ...> 
   ...> ;
   ...>
```

So... how do I get myself out of the prompt if `.quit`, `.exit`, and `;` all don't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out when I opened it up in a tmux window because it was getting annoying to keep killing the terminal tabs; just do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and that will dump you back in the shell:

```
sqlite> select * from files where strFilename like %Recreation%';
   ...> 
   ...> ;
   ...> ;
   ...> .quit
   ...> ;
   ...> .exit
   ...> ;
   ...> 
   ...> ;
   ...> 
Error: incomplete SQL: select * from files where strFilename like %Recreation%';

;
;
.quit
;
.exit
;

;
pi@raspbmc:~/.xbmc/userdata/Database$
```

Comment: This answer is equally useful when developing for Android. +1.